# Double subscript and superscript

Tags: latex, superscript

I have tried several approach and search for similar cases but I couldn't make this working.

[image]

As you can see the highlighted yellow looks improper and wrong. I would like to fix the following issues

1. make the subscript and superscript smaller
2. remove the space between sigma and its subscript
3. when I add sigma with subscript beta in the denominator they look like multiplication

I used the following code

```
$\beta_1,\frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{S_{xx}}$ and $\sigma^2_{\beta_i}$ and $\frac{\hat{\beta}_i-\beta_i}{\sigma_{\beta_i}}$
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the reputation to post an image, but here's a [link to a picture of one approach](http://lefft.xyz/img/latex-subsup-scripts.png)

More details below ~~

Hope this helps!

### Answer to 1)

Let's use the expression `\sigma^2_{\beta_i}`. The answers should apply within `\frac` as well.

A couple of ways to reduce the size -- compare these

```
% what we're starting from
$\sigma^2_{\beta_i}$
```

We can add an extra subscript layer using THAT, to get a smaller subscript (which auto-scales subsubscripts, like `i` here).

```
$\sigma^2_{\!_{\beta_i}}$
```

Or we can use `\mathsmaller` from the `relsize` package:

```
$\sigma^2_{\mathsmaller{\beta_i}}$
```

This combo seems to work well:

```
$\sigma^{\mathsmaller{2}}_{\!_{\beta_i}}$
```

### Answer to 2)

You can reduce space with an easy but kind of stupid hack (google for scaling negative space) -- just use `\hspace{}`.

Compare the starting point

```
% what we're starting from
$\sigma^2_{\beta_i}$
```

To beta-i with negative space:

```
\sigma^2_{\hspace{-.05in}\beta_i}$
```

### Answer to 3)

Put these two together, and you get:

```
% what we're starting from
$\sigma^2_{\beta_i}$

% what we end up with
$\sigma^{\mathsmaller{2}}_{\hspace{-.05in}\!_{\beta_i}}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale via `\scalebox{<factor>}` and/or raise via `\raisebox{<height>}`. Some horizontal adjustment is possible via `\!` (for more, see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/5764)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

$\beta_1,\frac{\sigma^{\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle 2$}}_{\!\epsilon}}{S_{xx}}$ and 
$\sigma^2_{\beta_i}$ and 
$\frac{\hat{\beta}_i-\beta_i}{\sigma_{\!\raisebox{-.1ex}{\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle \beta_i$}}}}$

\end{document}
```